# replace characters with space except period in numbers

Tags: python, regex

I currently have this function to replace specific unwanted characters.
Period is included. But I do not want to replace those that are in numbers.

```
description = description.strip()
replace_characters = "(){}[].*;?/'-&!,\""
for character in replace_characters:
    description = description .replace(ch, " ")
```

I have tried this but I cannot add the remaining replacement character in regex.

```
regex_str = r'(?<!\d)[.,;:](?!\d)'
list_amount = re.sub(regex_str, " ", description)
```

test cases. Comments are desired output

```
description = {2.4 oz/week.} #2.4 oz week
description = [yearly.] #yearly
description = (Current every day); #Current every day
```

Comment: `r'[,;:]|\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)'`

Comment: Please provide *test cases* i.e. pairs of input and desired outputs

Comment: @Daweo I added some

Comment: The regex seems to be working as expected? Removes periods if not in numbers.

Comment: The problem is I need to add the replace_characters in regex

Comment: Do you mean you want `regex_str = r'[' + replace_characters.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('-', r'\-').replace(']', r'\]').replace('^', r'\^') + r'](?!(?<=\d\.)\d)'`? See https://ideone.com/E0aU7I

Comment: Could you please let know what kind of code you expect? What parts of it? You say you do not need a regex alone, but a way to build the pattern dynamically?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  have expected to remove characters in replace_characters. The problem is with the decimal point. I need to retain the decimal point in numbers

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked, thanks! I cannot accept this solution unless you post it as an answer tho

Comment: So, `re.sub(r'''[(){}[\]*;?/'&!,"-]|\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)''', ' ', description)`? https://ideone.com/SnUvxD. What works for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one. Thank you so much! re.sub(r'''[(){}[\]*;?/'&!,"-]|\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)''', ' ', description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'''[(){}[\]*;?/'&!,"-]|\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)''', ' ', description)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NJXPFp/1). *Details*:

- `[(){}[\]*;?/'&!,"-]` - a char from the `(){}[]*;?/'&!,"-` list (note the escaped `]` and the `-` at the end of the character class, and the absence of the dot here)
- `|` - or
- `\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - a `.` that is not followed with a digit that is immediately preceded with a digit + `.`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SnUvxD):

```py
import re
description = "{2.4 oz/week.}".strip()
description = re.sub(r'''[(){}[\]*;?/'&!,"-]|\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)''', ' ', description)
print(description.strip()) # => 2.4 oz week
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
regex = r"(?<!\d)[\(\)\{\}\[\].*;?/'\-&!,\\\"](?!\d)"

test_str = ("2.4 oz/week. 5.\n"
    "[yearly.]\n"
    "(Current every day);")

subst = " "

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: I have added this test case since most text will have only this - {[(. e.g. {2.4 oz/week}